# Matching correct keys to symbols in plot legend using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I have plotted 2 graphs with both lines and symbols (such as diamonds and triangles). I then tried creating a legend to specify what the lines and symbols meant, but for some reason, the legend didn't match the keys to their correct symbols.
I know that lines/symbols should be graphed in the same order that you want the symbols to show up in the legend, but everything seems to be in the correct order in my code but it’s still not working.

Specifically, the first lines and symbols that I plotted don't even show up in the legend. Also, the last few symbols shown in the legend show up as repeats of the same symbol.

This is what the legend and plots look like currently:
[image: incorrect legend]

and this is how the legend should look:
[image: correct legend]

Edit: Here is the full code that plots the figures and the legend

```html
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 7))
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.35)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)

    ax1.plot(t, np.sum(x[:, [5, 6, 7, 14, 16, 18]], axis=1), 'k', linewidth=line_wdth)  # Total viral DNA
    ax1.plot(np.concatenate([dataTotalDNA[:, 0], dataTotalDNA[:, 0], dataTotalDNA[:, 0]]),
             np.concatenate([dataTotalDNA[:, 1], dataTotalDNA[:, 2], dataTotalDNA[:, 3]]),
             'k^', linewidth=line_wdth, markersize=10, markerfacecolor='none', markeredgewidth=2,
             markeredgecolor='black')
    plt.xlabel(r'Time (hpt)', fontsize=ftsz)

    if mode == 'manuscript':
        ax1.set_ylabel('AAV DNA copies/mL', fontsize=ftsz)
    if mode == 'presentation':
        ax1.set_title('AAV DNA copies/mL', fontsize=ftsz)

    ax1.set_xticks(range(0, 61, 12))
    ax1.tick_params(labelsize=ftsz)

    ax1.plot(t, np.sum(x[:, [16, 18]], axis=1), 'r', linewidth=line_wdth)  # Encapsidated DNA
    ax1.plot(np.concatenate([dataFullCap[:, 0], dataFullCap[:, 0], dataFullCap[:, 0]]),
             np.concatenate([dataFullCap[:, 1], dataFullCap[:, 2], dataFullCap[:, 3]]),
             'rs', linewidth=line_wdth, markersize=10, markerfacecolor='none', markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='red')
    ax1.plot([6, 6], [0, 7e9], 'k--', linewidth=1.2)  # Media exchange

    ax1.set_ylim([0, 7e9])
    ylim1 = ax1.get_ylim()
    xlim1 = ax1.get_xlim()

    if mode == 'manuscript':
        plt.text(-0.15 * xlim1[1], 1.01 * ylim1[1], r'A', fontsize=26, fontweight='bold')

    # Total capsid vs full capsid
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    ax2.plot(t, np.sum(x[:, [15, 16, 17, 18]], axis=1), 'b', linewidth=line_wdth)  # Total capsid
    ax2.plot(dataCap[:, 0], dataCap[:, 1], 'bd', markersize=10, linewidth=line_wdth, markerfacecolor='none',
             markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='blue')

    ax2.plot(t, np.sum(x[:, [16, 18]], axis=1), 'r', linewidth=line_wdth)  # Full capsid
    ax2.plot([dataFullCap[:, 0], dataFullCap[:, 0], dataFullCap[:, 0]],
             [dataFullCap[:, 1], dataFullCap[:, 2], dataFullCap[:, 3]],
             'rs', linewidth=line_wdth, markersize=10, markerfacecolor='none', markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='red',
             label='a')

    # Replicated DNA
    ax2.plot([6, 6], [0, 6e9], 'k--', linewidth=1.2)
    ax2.set_yscale('log')
    ax2.set_ylim([1e8, 1e11])

    ax2.set_xlim([0, 60])
    ax2.set_xticks(range(0, 61, 12))
    ax2.tick_params(labelsize=ftsz)

    ax2.set_xlabel('Time (hpt)', fontsize=ftsz)
    if mode == 'manuscript':
        ax2.set_ylabel('Capsids/mL (All Compartments)', fontsize=ftsz)
    elif mode == 'presentation':
        ax2.set_title('Capsids/mL (All Compartments)', fontsize=ftsz)

    ylim2 = ax2.get_ylim()
    xlim2 = ax2.get_xlim()

    if mode == 'manuscript':
        ax2.text(-0.22 * xlim2[1], 1.05 * ylim2[1], r'B', fontsize=26, fontweight='bold')

    labels = ['Replicated viral DNA - Data', 'Replicated viral DNA - Model',
              'Full virion - Data', 'Full virion - Model',
              'Total capsid - Data', 'Total capsid - Model']

    leg2 = plt.legend(labels, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.93, 1.127), ncol=3, fontsize=13)
    
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to understand without reproducible test code.  Could you add an example?  You might want to take a look at matplotlib's [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).   Normally, matplotlib takes care of matching legend symbols and corresponding text via the `label=` keyword added to the command that created the lines or scatter symbols.

Comment: I have clarified my question a bit. Does it now provide enough context?

Comment: Could you please add fully reproducible code, including the imports, correct indentation and some simple test data? If you want to combine the legends of two subplots, your reproducible test code needs to plot on two subplots. Did you try to add `label=` to `ax1.plot(..., label=...)` and use `hand1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()` as in the linked tutorial?

Comment: I have just edited my post to include the full code that plots the two subplots and the legend. I tried adding label=, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally preferred that you use the matplotlib provided options. While below is the fully custom option, would suggest you use this only if you are not able to use the matplotlib provided label options...

Below, I have created `matplotlib.lines` Line2D and created the lines, triangles, etc with the required colors manually and then used that as handles in the legend. Also, note that you need to use `labelcolor='markeredgecolor'` to enable the label color to match the `markeredgecolor` in this case. Hope this helps...

Note that, there is no data as none was available. Also, the color blue may need to change. As you only provided partial code and black was mentioned, not sure.. so used `tab:blue` here. Change as required.

```
# Code that creates first black line and black triangles on plot A:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

import matplotlib.lines as mlines
black_tri = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=0, marker='^',  markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', 
                          markersize=10, label='Replicated viral DNA - Data')
black_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=3, color='black', label='Replicated viral DNA - Model')
red_square = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=0, marker='s', markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='red', markerfacecolor='white',
                          markersize=10, label='Full virion - Data')
red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=3, color='red', label='Full virion - Model')
blue_diamond = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=0, marker='D', markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='tab:blue', markerfacecolor='white',
                          markersize=10, label='Total capsid - Data')
blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], lw=3, color='tab:blue', label='Total capsid - Model')

leg2=plt.legend(handles=[black_tri, black_line, red_square, red_line, blue_diamond, blue_line], loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.93, 1.2), 
                labelcolor='markeredgecolor', ncol=3, fontsize=13)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried using the code you have provided, but for some reason, it had no effect on the legend and gave me the same result. I had to remove the `handles=` and `labelcolor='markeredgecolor'` however, because I was getting errors when I had those in.

Comment: Is the code I provided not running as standalone (without including in your code)? Of course, the `handles=...` is required, without which the legend will not work. `labelcolor` will change the text color, but should be ok otherwise. Without knowing where/what the error is in your code, won't be able to say more

Comment: No, when I tried to run your code as a standalone, it gave me the error: `UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots. warnings.warn("No labeled objects found.")` It also shows me the 2 empty figures but there is no legend visible. I have added the entire code segment that handles plotting and creating the legends to my post above if that helps